# How to verify (and require) self-signed certificate in iOS

Tags: ios, security, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'd like to create an SSL connection to my server using self-signed certificates that are shipped with the code in iOS. That way I don't have to worry about more sophisticated man-in-the-middle attacks where someone has access to a high level "trusted" cert authority. I'm having issues doing so using what I believe to be Apple's standard way.

Generating the certificate, via the procedure found [here](http://svasey.org/projects/software-usage-notes/ssl_en.html)

```
# Create root CA & private key
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -sha512 -days 9999 -x509 -nodes -out root.pem.cer
# Create a certificate signing request
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -sha512 -nodes -out ssl.csr -keyout ssl.key
# Create an OpenSSL Configuration file from http://svasey.org/projects/software-usage-notes/ssl_en.html
vim openssl.conf
# Create the indexes
touch certindex
echo 000a > certserial
echo 000a > crlnumber
# Generate SSL certificate 
openssl ca -batch -config openssl.conf -notext -in ssl.csr -out ssl.pem.cer
# Create Certificate Revocation List
openssl ca -config openssl.conf -gencrl -keyfile privkey.pem -cert root.pem.cer -out root.crl.pem
openssl crl -inform PEM -in root.crl.pem -outform DER -out root.crl && rm root.crl.pem
```

And the iOS code:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
  NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [challenge protectionSpace];
  if ([protectionSpace authenticationMethod] == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust) {
    // Load anchor cert.. also tried this with both certs and it doesn't seem to matter
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"root.der" ofType:@"crt"];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    SecCertificateRef anchorCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFDataRef)data);
    CFMutableArrayRef anchorCerts = CFArrayCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
    CFArrayAppendValue(anchorCerts, anchorCert);

    // Set anchor cert
    SecTrustRef trust = [protectionSpace serverTrust];
    SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(trust, anchorCerts);
    SecTrustSetAnchorCertificatesOnly(trust, YES); // only use that certificate
    CFRelease(anchorCert);
    CFRelease(anchorCerts);

    // Validate cert
    SecTrustResultType secresult = kSecTrustResultInvalid;
    if (SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &secresult) != errSecSuccess) {
      [challenge.sender cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
      return;
    }

    switch (secresult) {
      case kSecTrustResultInvalid:
      case kSecTrustResultDeny:
      case kSecTrustResultFatalTrustFailure:
      case kSecTrustResultOtherError:
      case kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure: { 
        // !!! It's always kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure, aka 5
        NSLog(@"Failing due to result: %lu", secresult);
        [challenge.sender cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        return;
      }

      case kSecTrustResultUnspecified: // The OS trusts this certificate implicitly.
      case kSecTrustResultProceed: { // The user explicitly told the OS to trust it.
        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:trust];
        [challenge.sender useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        return;
      }
      default: ;
        /* It's somebody else's key. Fall through. */
    }
    /* The server sent a key other than the trusted key. */
    [connection cancel];

    // Perform other cleanup here, as needed.
  } else {
    NSLog(@"In weird space... not handling authentication method: %@", [protectionSpace authenticationMethod]);
    [connection cancel];
  }
}
```

I'm always getting kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure as the result. I don't think this is localhost issue as I've tried using Apple's code to change that too. What to do?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to override both `canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace` and `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge`. `TrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure` means you can change the outcome of the server validation. Also see OWASP's iOS public key pinning example at [Public Key Pinning](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning#iOS).

Answer (score 0):

If the trust result is *kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure*, you might be able to recover from the failure.

Here is the workaround.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW8

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure that your certificate is valid. I think it's name shouldn't be root.der.crt. You can take a look for certificate types from [here](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html). The below code is for p12 certificate, I hope it will help.

```
NSData *PKCS12DataQA = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CERTIFICATE NAME" ofType:@"CERTIFICATE TYPE"]];

BOOL result = [self extractIdentity:&identity andTrust:&trust fromPKCS12Data:PKCS12DataQA];


- (BOOL)extractIdentity:(SecIdentityRef *)outIdentity andTrust:(SecTrustRef*)outTrust fromPKCS12Data:(NSData *)inPKCS12Data
{
    OSStatus securityError = errSecSuccess;
    //testtest is the passsword for the certificate.
    NSDictionary *optionsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"testtest" forKey:(id)CFBridgingRelease(kSecImportExportPassphrase)];

    CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
    securityError = SecPKCS12Import((__bridge CFDataRef)(inPKCS12Data),(CFDictionaryRef)CFBridgingRetain(optionsDictionary),&items);

    if (securityError == 0) {
        CFDictionaryRef myIdentityAndTrust = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex (items, 0);
        const void *tempIdentity = NULL;
        tempIdentity = CFDictionaryGetValue (myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemIdentity);
        *outIdentity = (SecIdentityRef)tempIdentity;
        const void *tempTrust = NULL;
        tempTrust = CFDictionaryGetValue (myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemTrust);
        *outTrust = (SecTrustRef)tempTrust;

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed with error code %d",(int)securityError);
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```